# Why I can't get my freemarker template page (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, freemarker

I get 404 not found. What do I do wrong?

```
@GetMapping(PRIVACY_POLICY_ENDPOINT)
public String getPrivacyPolicyPage() {
    return "/privacyPolicy.ftlh";
}
```

Path:

```
src/main/resources/templates/privacyPolicy.ftlh
```

Gradle:

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
```

I tried to set properties, but it didn't help

```
  freemarker:
    enabled: true
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates
    suffix: .ftlh
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by deleting .ftlh from return